# Does Black Ops 2 (PC) allow local LAN multiplayer?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I want to LAN with my friends across our network in Black Ops 2 Multiplayer and Zombies. The question we would like to ask is: Does Black Ops 2 Support Local Area Play, like Rainbow Six:Vegas? or does it only support Online Play?

Comment: You could run it through tunngle.

Comment: Does the game itself not support LAN?

Comment: I don't beleive so.

Comment: Would the disc version of the game work with Tunngle? Or do I have to download skidrow?

Comment: This is for the PC version of course?

Comment: Yes. But all the tutorials I have seen said that the Game must be a skidrow download